# Header photo (above navbar) disappears when screen is minimized

Tags: html, css, mobile, header, navbar

In normal window size, my website contains the header photo, with Welcome and Travel Recommendations written over the photo, and at the bottom of the header, the navbar. I want it to look the same in mobile phone view, but the writing and header photo disappears every time I minimize the screen and the navbar moves on top of the page followed by the rest of the body content. Everything else works just fine. I'm just trying to find a way to keep the header photo in mobile view and the navbar below it. Thanks!

My HTML code is:

```
<style>
    .brand,
    .address-bar {
        text-align: center;
        background: url("img/photo.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        top: -10%;
        left: -10%;
        right: -10%;
        min-width: 110%;
        min-height: -10%;
        padding: 100px;
        font-size: 50px;
        color: black;
        margin-top:-1%;
    }
    ......
    @media screen and (min-width:768px) {
        .brand {
            display: inherit;
            margin: 0;
            text-align: right;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            font-family: "Josefin Slab", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 5em;
            font-weight: 700;
            line-height: normal;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .address-bar {
            display: inherit;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0 150px 400px;
            text-align: right;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 1.25em;
            font-weight: 400;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
            color: #fff;
        }
        ......
</style>
.....
<body>
    <div class="brand"> Welcome </div>
    <div class="address-bar"> Travel recommendations </div>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
             ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a flex-box or a css grid it's easy , below there is a link to a demo that i make for you to get a scaled and responsive header and navigation bar hope this help you have a good day.

**There is the demo :**

[Scaled header and nav-bar](http://codepen.io/rafongol/pen/NpWXBY/)

And of course don't **forget** to add to your `<head>` this code :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. The problem was that I did not have the photo class inside the header tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Try adding this to the top of the document. It should now scale the image. You shouldnt need the @mediascreen code in the css now.

Comment: Thank you! I will add that to the html.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things, your image should not disappear. But there are some things that you are doing which may cause the header photo to look like it is not displaying properly.

I would say that you should start debugging at the media-query.  Maybe try adding `display:block;` to your `.brand` class and maybe giving it a set height.  I think that might clear up some of your problems.

Also try adding a viewport meta to your html head, like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This will tell the browser how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

Also, that `min-height: -10%` you have on your `.address-bar` class is useless, that is not going to do anything.  a div cannot have a size smaller than `0`.

But if you say that it works full screen, try removing the entire media query and see if you still get the undesired result.  If not, there there is your place to start.

Comment: Thank you! I sorted it out. You are right, there is no need for min-height: -10%.